MongoDB aggregation with lookup pipeline
My mongoDB statistical query is not performing as expected even after I aggregate all of the queries into a mongoDB aggregation. The final query result still contains an incorrect value.
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "agencyId": ObjectId("649aedc8a827e7aed6ea7b79")  // Replace with the actual agency ID
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "OperationTransfer",  // Name of the transfer collection
            "localField": "_id",  // Field in operations referencing transfer document
            "foreignField": "operationId",  // Field in transfer collection
            "as": "transfer"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$transfer",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true  // Preserve operations without a transfer reference
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$status",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "countWithBabySeats": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$babySeats", true] }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            "countInTruck": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$inTruck", true] }, 1, 0]
                }
            },
            "countTransferWithNonEmptyOriginDestiny": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$ne": ["$transfer", null] },
                                { "$ne": ["$transfer.origin", ""] },
                                { "$ne": ["$transfer.destiny", ""] }
                            ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

countTransferWithNonEmptyOriginDestiny in this stage, I can't check if i have the transfer object and if it contains the appropriate attribute with the right values
I used $set to change the stage to update the result documents, but the values were still incorrect.
if i change preserveNullAndEmptyArraysto false
It will partially work but it will messing the result of the others counts
Example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/mue6QIFF0ej

Seems like you are missing the prefix: $ for the field referencing transfer, transfer.origin and transfer.destiny in your countTransferWithNonEmptyOriginDestiny field.

even with prefixing with $ i still didn't have the right result

maybe a better check to see if the field exists instead of checking for null in { "$ne": ["$transfer", null] }. because it returns true even if it doesnt exist since it is not technically null . maybe like { "$ne": [ { $type: "$transfer" }, "missing" ] }

@YongShun : here an example https://mongoplayground.net/p/mue6QIFF0ej

@cmgchess how do i check if it exists instead of null

replace with the one i gave https://mongoplayground.net/p/crN4aX3vBeX

cool you can post an answer if u want or let me know if i should

Like @cmgchechess comment, I should check if the field exists instead of checking for null
       "countTransferWithNonEmptyOriginDestiny": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$ne": [
                    {
                      $type: "$transfer"
                    },
                    "missing"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$transfer.origin",
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$transfer.destiny",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }

